# Add triangle to border to make an arrow

Tags: html, css, border

Say I have the following:

`<a href style="border: 1px blue solid; padding: 3px;">URL text here</a>`

to produce the following URL-in-a-box:

[image: URL without triangle]

How would I then go about modifying this to produce a URL-in-an-arrow?

Ideally, the blue arrow is just a single border, but a white-background shape with a blue border would be fine too.

[image]